# The primitive objects box isn't displayed in the tool shelf

Tags: modeling

I started using the 3d software, Blender and was following these tutorials. halfway through creating my project I notice the window, that is supposed to pop up after creating an object and let you adjust properties, wanst popping up. I tried searching for some answers because I just couldn't figure it out.

ex. ALT-A> Meshes> Cylinder> Then there is no window in the toolbar that should pop up.

I don't know if I hit something to disable this but I would appreciate it if I could get some suggestions.

p.s. No, I don't have any add-ons that are affecting the windows

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95207/why-does-panel-which-allows-edit-object-properties-no-longer-appear-in-the-tools)? Are the links suggested resolving that or not? If not explain why. If yes then no need to ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object primitive options are located in the tool shelf in the 3D viewport. You can toggle the tool shelf's visibility with the hotkey 'T'.

You can also press "F6" after creating an object to get the same options in a pop-up menu located at the mouse cursor.